# How to get flight schedules data?

Tags: air-travel, airports

I have looked everywhere for the past week to find the flight schedule origins. I know this information is coming from airlines and they will be discussed and sent to FAA. I wonder how some services like flightLabs are getting this data, which they turn into an API.

I just want to get a simple list of flights for a specific date between two airports and that seems to be a tough task to do using any API. I even thought of creating my own API, but now I don't know where to get my hands on this type of information.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you interested in the past, the present, or the future? And what data exactly would you need? And what coverage (countries)?

Comment: See https://rapidapi.com/collection/flight-data-apis for a few possible sources, but there are many others. Note that most require a payment, but a few will have limited free tiers, so it depends on how much data you need, at what frequency, and your use case after that.

Comment: @jcaron just the current and future flights. Yes, I have looked into that, but they have some high price tags for a little amount of data.

Answer (score 5):

This comes up regularly, and to the best of my knowledge, there is no free & reliable source of flight schedules.

You can purchase commercial subscriptions to various services that provide flight information, but expect to pay quite a bit for the privilege.  [OAG](https://www.oag.com/airline-schedules-data) is the original source of the data.

Comment: I would think there are alternative original sources for schedule data, especially the GDS (Amadeus, Galileo, Sabre...).

Comment: @jcaron GDSes source their information from OAG as well.

Comment: So all those services are paying OAG for the privilege and then charging their customers?

Comment: @MehraD Correct.

Comment: And how to become OAG? Are they scanning the airlines time tables? I know it might sound crazy, but we technically can scrape data from airlines and airports and get them together for a full flight schedule.

Comment: @MehraD Airlines willingly share their data with OAG, and this gives them their biggest advantage, visibility into *future* flights that have been announced but are not operating yet, and thus cannot be scraped from public data.